# <br> element not working between label and input

Tags: html, forms, input, label

EDIT: I had CSS code that prevented the `<br>` tag from inserting a single line break

I've been trying to create a login page, and I wanted to center the Username inserting block and the Password inserting block, I have used the 
 tag to accomplish that, but it doesn't work; see screenshot. Any help is appreciated, thank you
here is the code:

```html
<div class="login">
  <form action="#">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN">
  </form>
</div>
```

[here's how the code renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RLGQ.png)

Comment: All else being equal: That is **not** how that code renders. You must have forgotten to include something in the question. You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="login">
    <form action="#">
        <label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br/><br/>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN">
    </form>
</div>
```

try this

Comment: Hit the button "Run code snippet"

Comment: Okay, thank you! Turns out some code in CSS that was preventing the elements from taking the shape I wanted them to.

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot the difference than an answer … and doesn’t seem to solve the problem anyway. If one br has no effect — which it clearly does with the code in the question so there must be something the OP left out which is stopping it from working — then adding a second one is unlikely to help (because the OP’s missing code is going to affect it in the same way).